# passing array object to javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sharepoint-2013

I am creating dynamic link where I am passing function with some values and array but when that function is called that array become string like **"[object Object]"**. It don't remain as array

`Javascript Code`

```
var mdata = {};
            mdata.itemId = data.d.ID.toString();
            mdata.sucessMsg = "Gate Pass detail document is uploaded successfully.";
            mdata.errorMsg = "Gate Pass detail document uploading cancel";
            tdUplDoc.html("<a id='uplDoc' href='#' onclick=\"javascript:openBasicDialog('UploadDocument.aspx','Upload CivilID or Passport Copy','" + mdata + "');\">Upload Documents</a>");
```

`calling function`

```
function openBasicDialog(tUrl, tTitle, tdata) {
    var options = {
        url: tUrl,
        title: tTitle,
        args: tdata,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: onPopUpCloseCallBackWithData
    };
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
    return false;
}
```

How I will keep my array as array not as string. Something I am doing wrong. Please somebody help me :(

Comment: Learn to use DOM instead of trying to build a DOM by mashing together strings of HTML.

Comment: Please don't be rude. this is the part of my code which i am using to make dynamic table

Comment: I'm not being rude. Your technique is error prone and overly complicated. DOM would make things much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as a JSON string,

```
"'..,'" + JSON.stringify(mdata) + "');\">Upload Documents</a>");
```

And use it inside the function after parsing,

```
function openBasicDialog(tUrl, tTitle, tdata) {
    var options = {
        url: tUrl,
        title: tTitle,
        args: JSON.parse(tdata),  //parse it here
        dialogReturnValueCallback: onPopUpCloseCallBackWithData
    };
```

Comment: Your solution works out but as mdata was having string it was giving error for unterminated string which I resolve by  JSON.stringify(mdata).replace(/\"/g, '&quot;')  Thank you again

Comment: @Milind Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This won't work do the following

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.id = 'uplDoc';
a.href='#';
a.addEventListener('click', function(){
  openBasicDialog('UploadDocument.asp', 'Upload CivilID or Passport Copy', mdata);  
}
tdUplDoc.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `[object Object]` because you are doing a string concatenation and that is the string representation of this object:

```
"<a id='uplDoc' href='#' onclick=\"javascript:openBasicDialog('UploadDocument.aspx','Upload CivilID or Passport Copy','" + mdata + "');\"
```

What I would suggest is to add the element and write a `click` [event listener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) on that element:

```
tdUplDoc.html("<a id='uplDoc' href='#'>Upload Documents</a>");

document.getElementById('uplDoc').addEventListener('click', function(){
   openBasicDialog('UploadDocument.asp', 'Upload CivilID or Passport Copy', mdata);  
});
```